# Django dictionary from env settings issue or django_rq issue?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-rq

I'm facing a strange behavior when trying to create Django_rq queues configuration dynamically from an environment variable.

my env var is :

```
CUSTOM_QUEUES=default:q1:q2
```

into my settings.py I have:

```
from getenv import env



# Cache
CACHES_DEFAULT = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1"
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": env("CACHE_URL", CACHES_DEFAULT),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
        'TIMEOUT': 3600
    },
}


RQ_QUEUES_REDIS = {'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default'}
RQ_QUEUES = {k:RQ_QUEUES_REDIS for k in env('CUSTOM_QUEUES', "default").split(':')}
```

I'm expecting the denerated RQ_QUEUES dict to be like this one which is working :

```
RQ_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default',
    },
    'q1': {
        'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default',
    },
    'q2': {
        'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default',
    },
}
```

even though the configuration seems to run well and I can see the queues from django_rq web page, my workers cannot connect and actually throw this error as like there's no queue key in redis

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 350, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 342, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 348, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 399, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/management/commands/rqworker.py",
>   line 79, in handle
>       queues = get_queues(*args)   File "/home/work/virtualenv/runaway_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py",
>   line 166, in get_queues
>       queue_params = QUEUES[queue_names[0]] KeyError: 'default'

By The Way: if I use the Static configuration above it just works well, so my suspect is more focused on Django_rq not creating the queues but maybe I'm also doing something unproper on the settings of Django.

Any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

F.